# На графике flotcharts значения выровнены не по сетке

Tags: диаграммы, chart.js

Использую (учусь использовать) в проекте построение графиков с помощью flot (www.flotcharts.org).
На графике значения не совпадают с сеткой, т.е. значение смещено левее по оси Х.

[image: График]

Опции и вывод графика

```
var options = {
            grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                clickable: true
            },
            series: {
                color: "#0865FD",
                lines: {
                    show: true
                },
                points: {
                    show: true
                }
            },
            xaxis: {
                mode: "time",
                timeformat: "%d.%m.%Y",
                minTickSize: [1, "day"]
            },
            yaxis: {
                tickDecimals: 0
            }
        };

        $("#modal_charts").show();
        var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", [data], options);
```

В чем косяк?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в неверном часовом поясе.
Просто добавил 3 часа ко времени 
    `time.add(3, 'hours');`